# Guitar Tuner or Guitar effects Algorithms?

Tags: fft, algorithms, digital

I need to explore the algorithm of the digital guitar tuner or the digital guitar effects algorithms.
Is there any Book or articles that you recommend of?

All I know is that relate to DSP.

thanks

Comment: Make sure to look for articles and research papers on pitch estimation or detection, and ignore simple windowed FFT single peak magnitude frequency estimators, as the latter are quite unreliable for guitars.

Comment: @hotpaw2 thanks, can you recommend about some articles?

Comment: Here's a blog post I wrote: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/07/frequency-detection-using-fft-aka-pitch.html

Comment: Some mixed quality stuff here: http://www.amazon.com/Digital-Audio-Java-Craig-Lindley/dp/0130876763

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best book on the topic is probably [http://www.amazon.com/DAFX-Digital-Udo-ouml-lzer/dp/0470665998](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470665998).

There is some freeware stuff (very mixed quality) here: http://www.musicdsp.org/

Many companies spend a lot of effort in making good sounding effects and well working tuners to make money with it, so access to "good" non-commercial sources if fairly limited.

Comment: thanks a lot, do you know if this book explains about the algorithm? or show the pseudo code or something? because this is what i need also.. :)

Comment: "Many companies spend a lot of effort in making ... well working tuners".  Maybe a *few* companies do that, but I think most just sell pre-made mediocre solutions and invest their money in the packaging and marketing, not the functionality.